# Control XBee configuration through Linux

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, xbee

How can I change XBee mode from coordinator to router and vice versa using Raspberry Pi (or Linux terminal in general)?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: https://python-xbee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @Forklift i found a way to change simple xbee configuration (baudrate, PAN ID, ...) from this link (https://github.com/XBeeInternetGateway/XIG/wiki/Linux-installation)  but no way to change its mode (coordinator and router)

Comment: @cricket_007 i saw this link, but it hasn't a way to change router-coordinator mode.

Comment: Some modules support `ATCE` for "coordinator enable".  Set to 1 for coordinator and 0 for router.  But other XBee modules have separate firmware builds for router and coordinator.

Comment: @tomlogic, in the datasheet they said that there're a firmware including the 6 firmware (Coordinator AT, Coordinator API, Router AT, Router API, End Device AT, and End Device API), where could i find it?

Comment: Download XCTU from www.digi.com. It's a Mac/Windows/Linux GUI for installing firmware and configuring XBee modules.

Comment: @tomlogic, i want to configure XBee without XCTU, i have 4 XBee including one coordinator, i want to change the coordinator while the system is running if some condition is true, got my point?

Comment: If you're using Python, take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XBee

Comment: If you change the coordinator's settings, it will form a new network. If you switch to a router configuration, you'll need a coordinator to form a new network. You would rarely make a change like that outside of commissioning a network.

Comment: @tomlogic so as i understand, you mean i should configure the routers after changing the coordinator, right? also i'm using XBee S2B, does it support changing the value of ATCE to switch from coordinator to router and vice versa?

Comment: i looked at the XBee library but i didn't find anything related to the switching i need.

Comment: The XBee S2B has different firmware builds for Router and Coordinator node types.  I highly recommend using XCTU for doing firmware installations.  If that isn't an option, there's an [Open Source ANSI C Library](https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee_ansic_library) that includes a command-line program for S2B firmware updates that you can compile on the RPi.

Comment: @tomlogic Using this library, can i upload different firmwares on the xbee while the code is working? (coordinator or router)

Comment: No, it boots into the XBee boot loader to upload new firmware, and then you'll need to configure it with network settings. Something you'd typically do only when setting up your network. Why do you need to change node type on deployed network? Creating a new coordinator means routers will have to join that new network.

Comment: @tomlogic i'm working on a project which i have to handle the case of coordinator failure by choosing another XBee to be coordinator, so i'm searching for a way to do that using XBee S2B.

Comment: I believe that an S2B network, once established, will survive the loss of the coordinator.  The XBee S2C might be a better radio to base your project on, since you can just make use of the `ATCE` setting.  Don't forget to have modules on the old network leave and re-join to the newly commissioned network.

Comment: i'm thinking in that too,Thank you